# Changing the border length in CSS

Tags: html, css, border

I realize that borders wrap the content but is it possible to make the bottom border percentage of the element it is bordering? Also is it possible to reduce the border length by a set pixels i.e. -20px.

```
nav li {
display: inline-block;
*display: inline; /*For Internet Explorer 7*/
*zoom: 1; /*For Internet Explorer 7*/
padding: 10px;
font-family: "Changa One" , Cursive;
font-size: 1em;
}

nav li:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
padding-bottom: 3px;    
}
```

When I hover I want the bottom border (udnerline) to be reduced by 20px because my padding spaces the list elements by 20px (10px both sides). Any answers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use margin to space your elements rather than padding if you don't want the border to show on the space in between elements.

With regard to the other question, I don't think you can use % for a border.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it will help

http://jsfiddle.net/jk43ej0g/

```css
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav{}
nav li {
display: inline-block;
*display: inline; /*For Internet Explorer 7*/
*zoom: 1; /*For Internet Explorer 7*/
padding: 10px;
font-family: "Changa One" , Cursive;
font-size: 1em;
}



nav li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

nav li:hover a{
    border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
    padding-bottom: 3px;    
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1000</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1000</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```